# I want to `start_time` and `end_time` count how can get this?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How can count between `start_time` and `end_time` time

```
$time_all = Carbon::now()->toArray();

if ($input['type'] == 'start') {
                  /*  $data = [
                        'start_time' => $time, 'contract_id' => $input['job_id'],'engineer_id' => $userid, 'type' => 'start'
                    ];*/

$start_time = JobTimingLog::create([
                        'start_time' => $time, 'contract_id' => $input['job_id'],'engineer_id' => $userid, 'type' => 'start'
                    ])->id;
$arr = array("status" => 200, "message" => "start_time Add Successfully", "data" => array('start_time' => $time, 'id' => $start_time));
} else if ($input['type'] == 'end') {
$data_end = DB::table('job_timing_logs')->where('contract_id', $input['job_id'])->where('id', $input['id'])->update(['end_time' => $time, 'type' => 'end']);
$arr = array("status" => 200, "message" => "end_time update Successfully", "data" => $times);
}
```

**Now I want to count between start_time  and end_time**

Comment: cant understand . Could you please explain bit more

Comment: Do you want to take the difference ?

Comment: On start you are creating record and on end you are updating record, right ?

Comment: yes i want difference @ Nipun Tharuksha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify where did you get the `$time` variable content and in what format is it, I'll assume `$time` is start datetime and `$end_time` is end datetime and you want to take the time difference between those two. It can be done using [Carbon difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) package like this:

```
// Assume $time = '2019-12-06 00:00:00' and $end_time = '2019-12-06 18:00:00'
$start_time = Carbon::parse($time); // Parse the datetime to Carbon object first
$end_time = Carbon::parse($end_time);
$diff_in_hours = $start_time->diffInHours($end_time);
$diff_in_minutes = $start_time->diffInMinutes($end_time);
$diff_in_seconds = $start_time->diffInSeconds($end_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon's [difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) methods to get the difference between two Carbon objects.

For example, if you wanted the difference between `$start_date` and `$end_date` in a CarbonInterval object, you could do something like this:

```php
$start_date->diffAsCarbonInterval($end_date)
```